# The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have a problem in this code

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Net.Mail
Public Class SendEmail

    Private _Mailto As String = ""
    Public Property Mailto() As String
        Get
            Return _Mailto
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Mailto = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _MailSub As String = ""
    Public Property MailSub As String
        Get
            Return _MailSub
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _MailSub = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _MailBody As String = ""
    Public Property MailBody As String
        Get
            Return _MailBody
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _MailBody = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _Msg As String = ""
    Public ReadOnly Property Msg As String
        Get
            Return _Msg
        End Get
    End Property


    Public Sub email()
        Try
            Dim mail As New MailMessage()
            Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
            mail.From = New MailAddress("email@gmail.com")
            mail.[To].Add(_Mailto)
            mail.Subject = _MailSub
            mail.Body = _MailBody
            ' mail.Headers.Add("In-Reply-To", 1)
            SmtpServer.Port = 587
            SmtpServer.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("email@gamil.com", "password")

            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
            SmtpServer.Send(mail)

            _Msg = " Check Your Mail "
        Catch ex As Exception
            _Msg = ex.Message
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

and the exception is :The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.: any soultion??

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're initializing _MailTo to an empty string (""), then setting the "To" email address to that value. Unless you're setting the value of that field to some valid email address, the email sender won't recognize an empty string as a valid email address.

(If you are setting the MailTo property from outside the given code, you'll need to provide code to show where you're setting it and what the value is.)

Comment: this code exist in form and consist of button and textbox called "txtemail"
Protected Sub Send_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Send.Click
        Dim objemail As New SendEmail
        objemail.Mailto = txtEmail.Text
        objemail.email()
        LabelEmail.Text = "The email has been sent"
    End Sub

Comment: @Alaahafethburghall: Please update your question with what you just posted. Code is incredibly hard to read in the comments area.

Comment: @Alaahafethburghall: Also, show what input you are providing in the textbox before you click the Send button. Have you stepped through it in the debugger to see what the value of _MailTo value is when your code is running?